# Как сделать закруглённые кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


sm = ScreenManager()
Window.size = (375, 700)
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)

Builder.load_string("""
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<HomeScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        padding: 40
        Button:
            background_normal: '1.png'
            size_hint: [.3, .15]
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'add'
<AddScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            height:Window.height * 1.5
            orientation : 'vertical'
            padding: 20
            spacing: 20
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'
            Button:
                text: 'press'

""")



class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class AddScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='HOME'))
sm.add_widget(AddScreen(name='add'))
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().run()
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: есть кнопки они квадратные а надо закруглённые

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005182/rounding-button-corners-in-kivy

Comment: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/MDButtons

Comment: Спасибо Xyanight